# Highstock line chart series processedYData is wrong

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[Photo with faulty chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlLps.png) | [Zooming in (less data points) plots correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdy0d.png)When charting a boolean value over time (as stepped), Highstock 7.2.0 is introducing interpolated values between 0 and 1.  I would like the result to just plot 0s and 1s in a stepped fashion.  See attached photos.  The one marked up is showing interpolated values.

I'm looking at the difference between series.data and series.processedYData and while series.data is a mix of 0s and 1s as expected, series.processedYData contains some interpolated values between 0 and 1.  If I zoom in on the affected time range, it renders correctly.  It is only happening when pulling in larger set of data (over 100 or so).

```
scope.CreateChart = function () {
    if (scope.chart) scope.chart.destroy();
    scope.chart = new Highcharts.stockChart('trend', {
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled:false
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            enabled:true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            connectNulls: false
        },


        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%b %e',
                week: '%b %e',
                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{ id: GuidSvc.Create(), title: { text: 'Default' }, opposite: false }],
        series: [
            {name: 'Series 1', 
             step: true,
             type: 'line',
             data: [[1568293051542,0],[1568293352761,0],[1568293652277,0]
        ],
        credits: { enabled: false },
        lang: {
            noData: "No tags selected.  Click on a tag to trend"
        },
        noData: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '15px',
                color: '#ccc'
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Your description doesn't contain a question. Could you make it more obvious what you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks, updated and added a couple images for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening probably because of series `dataGrouping`. It is the concept of sampling the data values into larger blocks in order to ease readability and increase performance.

So the solution could be to disable it or change the approximation method so that it shows not group average but one of its points (so that it will be 0 or 1).

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
```

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping
- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.approximation